# Should Django foreign key relationships be user to model or model to user?

Tags: sql, django, database, django-models, foreign-keys

I am new to django and trying to make an ecommerce website for practice. There is a `Cart` model which currently has a **ForeignKey** to the `User`. Which way is more efficient?

Should I create a `UserProfile` model which would have a Cart as the ForeignKey or should I keep it like this?

I am thinking the former should be faster as when I will display the cart to the user, it will have to search and filter through all carts if I keep it as is. But the tutorials I am watching are setting up their models in which Cart has a ForeignKey to the User.

Comment: Cart should have the UserProfile as a FK. If carts have one-to-one relationship with UserProfile, you can also use OneToOneField.

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın Can you explain how is it more efficient as it will have to search through all the carts to find the user's cart. Do websites with big database also have it set up like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was writing this in the comment but it turns out to be longer than the allowed number of characters.

To answer your question: `Can you explain how is it more efficient as it will have to search through all the carts to find the user's cart. Do websites with big database also have it set up like this?`

Yes, they do. If you add the cart to the UserProfile as FK, it's not supposed to be faster because it only holds the reference to that cart instance. You still have to go to the Cart table and retrieve the relevant row. The thing you have to be careful about is to keep control of the number of queries made to the database. To track that, you can use `django-debug-toolbar`, or debug it using the shell.

```
from django.db import connection
queries=connection.queries

print(f"QUERY: {len(queries)}")
```

and then check the length of the queries and their details to debug and make it faster. Also, use `select_related` and `prefetch_related` whenever possible which will decrease the number of queries made significantly.

Django debug toolbar looks like this

[image: ddt]

And when you click on the `SQL`, you'll see all the queries made in detail and be able to see the duplicate queries.